# How do I make a button unclickable for a period of time?

Tags: java, android

How do I make a button unclickable for a period of time?

Ask for more information if needed.

This is on android.

Answer (score 3):

if you want unclickable Button then you can use **Button.setEnabled(false);**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TimerTask` which runs at a specified time **repeaditly** or **once**. Please refer [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) document.

Answer (score 1):

Untested Code

You can use a `handler`. The given code make your **button unclickable for 1.5 seconds**. and then re enable it.

```
int Delay = 1500; //1.5 seconds
yourView.setEnabled(false);// for making the button grey and unclickable

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {  
        yourView.setEnabled(true);
    }
},Delay);
```

**Second Method**

```
//initiate the button
 button.setEnabled(true);
 button.invalidate(); 
 // delay completion till animation completes
 button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {  //delay button 
     public void run() {  
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.invalidate();
        //any other associated action
     }
 }, 800);  // .8secs delay time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first disable your button with `setEnabled(false)` and use [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) to enable it again after a specific period of time

Answer (score 0):

An interesting thing you could do is use an `ObjectAnimator` and animate an int value from 0 to 1. I'll try this later.